# how to automatically close infoWindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

gurus, greeting:

I have a question regarding javascript. I wrote a javascript patch to display multiple markers on a Google map. The geocoding and related information of these markers are retrieved from database, and I pass the data with JSON in APEX. The problem is: I want to close infowindow of a marker if user click another marker. I tried to set up with only one global variable of infowindow, it did achieve my purpose, infowindow automatically close when I click another marker, but every marker got same content in infowindow. COuld any one help me on this problem? your help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code

```
<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#1938.JPG"\><script type="text/javascript"           src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var infoWindow;

function initialize() {

    //var test_geo=$v('P3016_H_RESIDENT_GEOCODING');
    //alert(test_geo);

    var myOptions = { zoom: 18, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var point=new google.maps.LatLng(&P3016_H_RESIDENT_GEOCODING.);

    markerBounds.extend(point);
    map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-8);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });

    var json_obj = $v('P3016_H_JSON');
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_obj);
    var markers= new Array();
    var current_parameter;
    var my_URL;
    var test_prefix = $v('P3016_H_APEX_PREFIX');


    for (var u = 0; u < obj.Offenders.length; u++){
        var user = obj.Offenders[u];

        markers[u] = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.Offenders[u].LA,obj.Offenders[u].LO), map: map });
        current_parameter ="&APP_ID.:216:&SESSION.::NO::O:"+user.cs;
        my_URL=my_URL=test_prefix+encodeURIComponent(current_parameter);


        my_URL='<a href='+my_URL+'>'+user.Name+'</a>'+'\n'+user.Addr;

        addInfoWindow(markers[u], my_URL);
    }



    function addInfoWindow(marker, message) {
        var info = message;

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: message
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            //if (infoWindow.getMap()){
             //   infowWindow.close();
            //}

            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }


    var radius_in_miles=$v('P3016_H_RADIUS_M');
    var circle = {
        strokeColor: "#ff0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#ff0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.20,
        map: map,
        center: point,
        radius: 1609.3*radius_in_miles   };

    var drawCirle = new google.maps.Circle(circle);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call setContent() on the global infoWindow before you open() it. To get the right message you can store the user id in the marker and construct the message when it's needed, I.e. markers[u].user_id = u; 
In the click handler you can then use this.user_id to get the user from your offenders array.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow